# Why It doesn't work when I declare my variable before?

Tags: c#, variables

I worked on an edabit challenge for hours and finally, I resolved this challenge by error.

**Here's what didn’t work:**

```cs
/*****************************/ 

public static bool IsStrangePair(string str1, string str2)
{
    char firstCharInStr1 = str1[0];
    char lasttCharInStr1 = str1[str1.Length-1];
    char firstCharInStr2 = str2[0];
    char lasttCharInStr2= str2[str2.Length-1];
    
    if (str1.Length == 0 && str2.Length == 0)
        return true;

    if (str1.Length == 0 || str2.Length == 0)
        return false;

    return firstCharInStr1 == lasttCharInStr2 && lasttCharInStr1 == firstCharInStr2;
}
```

So I add `IsNull` at the beginning and it worked :S - **why?**

```cs
public static bool IsStrangePair(string str1, string str2)
{
    // A What I add after
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
    {
        return str1 == str2;
    }

    char firstCharInStr1 = str1[0];
    char lasttCharInStr1 = str1[str1.Length-1];
    char firstCharInStr2 = str2[0];
    char lasttCharInStr2= str2[str2.Length-1];
    
    // B-----My first idea
    if (str1.Length == 0 && str2.Length == 0)
        return true;
    
    if (str1.Length == 0 || str2.Length == 0)
        return false;

    return firstCharInStr1 == lasttCharInStr2 && lasttCharInStr1 == firstCharInStr2 ;
```

I didn't understood why it was validate because I was under the impression that my A "`IsNullOrEmpty` solution" was the repetition of my First Idea so it was insane (for me).

So I understood(i think) that I had to choose between A or B and that the key is to declare my variable AFTER my B or my A ( I have too choose B OR A)

So I'm confused cause I was thinking that we had to declare variables before to start/or use it. Why It doest work when my variables are declared First?

I wish I'm clear

Comment: if a string is null or empty it has no `[0]` index (requires at least one char in string) so it will fail trying to access index[0]. You have already defined the variables, when you pass them as parameters.

Comment: You could also just move the lines `var firstCharInStr1 = ...` etc. after the lines with the `if` statements. The reason was already explained by @PoulBak.

Comment: Merci pour votre aide  Messieurs !! J'en prends soigneusement note !

Answer (score 0):

Null can be confusing when first starting up.
Null is not an actual value but rather an empty pointer (if you are familiar with pointers). This means that you have declared a name but you have not actually pointed to any value.

Think of it as you have declare that you want a house of type mansion, but did not declare an address. It is impossible to open maindoor on, but you can check if the address is absent.

You can check for null, you can even in some cases use it to your benefit, however in your case you are trying to take the [0] in a thing that does not exist (is null).

And therefor you have the wonderful option to use string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToBeTested);

In dot.net 6 you will find green squickly lines everywhere a variables risks being null.

Comment: Je vous remercie d'avoir trouver le temps de répondre à ma demande.  L'exemple du manoir est très visuel et pertinente. Je vais faire de mon mieux pour travailler dessus en m'aidant de votre réponse pour bien comprendre ! Je note soigneusement string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToBeTested); Merci Beaucoup !